# how to differentiate background from foreground in pyqt5

Tags: pyqt5

I am trying to differentiate bits of  background from foreground image in pyqt5.I am splitting the Qgraphicitem into bits and saving it as png image based on 16*16 pixel grids

I have tried the following code

```
[![from PyQt5.QtCore import (QByteArray, QDataStream, QIODevice,QObject, QMimeData, QPointF, QPoint, Qt,pyqtProperty, QRect,QTimer,QLineF, QEvent,QRectF)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QDrag, QPainter, QPixmap,QFont,QFontMetrics,QBrush, QLinearGradient, QIcon, QPen, QPainterPath,QKeySequence, QTransform,QCursor,QMouseEvent,QClipboard
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QSplitterHandle,QApplication,QGraphicsScene,QGraphicsView,QWidget,QFontDialog,QHBoxLayout,QLabel,QMenu ,QGraphicsTextItem,QColorDialog,QGraphicsItemGroup,QGraphicsPixmapItem,QGraphicsRectItem,QMessageBox, QFormLayout,QSizePolicy, QScrollArea,QShortcut, QPushButton,QDialogButtonBox,QGroupBox,QLineEdit, QMainWindow,QInputDialog, QGraphicsPathItem,QDialog, QVBoxLayout,QGraphicsItem,QStatusBar


class GraphicsSceneClass(QGraphicsScene):
    global selectedObjType
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GraphicsSceneClass, self).__init__(parent)
        self.gridOn = 0
        self.setSceneRect(0, 0, 1920, 1080)
        self.setItemIndexMethod(QGraphicsScene.NoIndex)
        self.setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(Qt.black))

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
            sampleTransform = QTransform()
            objectAtMouse = self.itemAt(event.scenePos(), sampleTransform)

            if objectAtMouse and event.button()== Qt.LeftButton:
                objectAtMouse.setSelected(True)

            elif objectAtMouse==None and event.button()==Qt.RightButton:
                # pass
                self.grid = self.TargPosForLine(event.scenePos(), "ForLine")
            self.grid = self.TargPosForLine(event.scenePos(), "ForLine")

    def TargPosForLine(self, position, mode):

        clicked_column = int((position.y() // 16)) * 16
        clicked_row = int((position.x() // 16)) * 16
        if clicked_column < 0:
            clicked_column = 0
        if clicked_row < 0:
            clicked_row = 0
        if (mode == "ForRect"):
            return QRect(clicked_row, clicked_column, 16, 16)
        elif (mode == "ForLine"):
            return QPointF(clicked_row, clicked_column)

    def DeselectItems(self):
        selectedObjects = self.selectedItems()
        for object in selectedObjects:
            object.setSelected(False)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        # self.DeselectItems()
        pass

    def textassign(self):
        self.dialog = QDialog()
        self.Gearname = QLabel("Name")
        self.Gearnameedit = QLineEdit()
        buttonBox = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        # buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)
        hbox = QFormLayout()
        hbox.addRow(self.Gearname, self.Gearnameedit)
        hbox.addRow(buttonBox)
        self.dialog.setLayout(hbox)
        self.dialog.exec()

    def accept(self):
        text = self.Gearnameedit.text()
        # self.objectdrop._text
        self.font = QFont()
        self.font.setPixelSize(20)
        self.font.setBold(False)
        self.font.setFamily("Arial Unicode MS")
        self.text = QGraphicsTextItem()
        self.text.setPlainText(str(text))
        self.text.setFont(self.font)
        self.text.setDefaultTextColor(Qt.darkGreen)
        self.addItem(self.text)
        self.text.setPos(self.grid.x() + 20, self.grid.y() - 35)
        # print("y", y)
        self.text.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
        self.text.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        self.text.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIgnoresTransformations)
        # self.objectdrop.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
        # self.text._position = QPointF(y.x() + 20, y.y() - 35)
        self.text._type1 = "Text"
        self.text._txtvalue = text
        print(self.text._txtvalue)
        self.dialog.close()
    def createbitmap(self,objectDrop,gridPos):
        w = 0
        h = 0
        self.objectdrop = objectDrop
        pixmap = QPixmap(objectDrop._width, objectDrop._height)
        pixmap.fill(Qt.transparent)

        painter1 = QPainter(pixmap)
        painter1.setPen(Qt.NoPen)
        painter1.setBrush(objectDrop.brush())
        # painter1.setClipPath(objectDrop.path())

        painter1.setRenderHint(QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing)
        # painter1.setOpacity(0.5)
        painter1.setBackgroundMode(0)
        painter1.drawPath(objectDrop.path())
        count = objectDrop._width // 16
        pixmap.save("point.png")
        # mid = self.TargPosForLine(objectDrop._midPos, "ForRect")
        rect = QRect(16,0, 16, 16)
        cropped = QPixmap(pixmap.copy(rect))
        cropped.save("bit.png")

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    global selectedObjType

    # global item
    def __init__(self, ):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        #

        self.scene = GraphicsSceneClass()
        MainWindow.obj = self.scene
        self.view = QGraphicsView(self.scene)
        # self.view.setDragMode(QGraphicsView.RubberBandDrag)
        self.view.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.view.setRenderHint(QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing)
        self.widg = QWidget()
        self.horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.view)
        self.widg.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.widget.setLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
        self.obj = None

    def deleteItem(self):
        for item in self.scene.selectedItems():
            self.scene.removeItem(item)

    def selectAll(self):

        for item in self.scene.items():
            item.setSelected(True)

    def GridOnOffControl(self):
        if self.scene.gridOn == 0:
            self.scene.gridOn = 1
        else:
            self.scene.gridOn = 0
        if self.scene.gridOn == 1:
            self.scene.setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(QPixmap('images/Grid.png')))
        else:
            self.scene.setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(Qt.black))

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        contextMenu = QMenu(self)

        Cutaction = contextMenu.addAction("Cut")
        Coaction = contextMenu.addAction("Copy")
        Paaction = contextMenu.addAction("Paste")
        Propaction = contextMenu.addAction("draw1")
        quitAct = contextMenu.addAction("quit")
        action = contextMenu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(event.pos()))
        if action == quitAct:
            self.close()

        elif action == Propaction:
            objectDrop = None
            painterPath = QPainterPath()

            painterPath.moveTo(10.0, 0.0)
            painterPath.arcTo(0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 4.0, 90.0, 90.0)
            painterPath.lineTo(0.0, 4.0)
            painterPath.arcTo(0.0, 2.0, 4.0, 4.0, 180.0, 90.0)
            painterPath.lineTo(112 - 6, 6.0)
            painterPath.arcTo(112 - 8, 2.0, 4.0, 4.0, 270.0, 90.0)
            painterPath.lineTo(112 - 4, 2.0)
            painterPath.arcTo(112 - 8, 0.0, 4.0, 4.0, 0.0, 90.0)
            gradient = QLinearGradient(1, 1, 1, 5)
            gradient.setColorAt(0, QColor(Qt.gray))
            gradient.setColorAt(0.5, QColor(192, 192, 192, 255))
            gradient.setColorAt(1, QColor(Qt.darkGray))
            painterPath.closeSubpath()

            objectDrop = QGraphicsPathItem()
            objectDrop.setPath(painterPath)
            objectDrop.setBrush(QBrush(gradient))
            objectDrop.setPos(self.scene.grid)
            objectDrop._positon=QPointF(self.scene.grid.x(),self.scene.grid.y())
            objectDrop._endPos=QPointF(objectDrop._positon.x()+112,objectDrop._positon.y())
            objectDrop._width=objectDrop._endPos.x()-objectDrop._positon.x()
            objectDrop._height=16
            self.scene.addItem(objectDrop)
            objectDrop.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
            objectDrop.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
            self.scene.textassign()
            self.scene.createbitmap(objectDrop,self.scene.grid)



    def selectedItem(self):
        items = self.scene.selectedItems()

        if len(items) == 1:
            return items\[0\]
        return None
if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()

    mainWindow.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())][1]][1]
```

If i give  rect = QRect(16,0, 16, 16)it will give image 1[image][image: Image1]

if rect = QRect(0,16,16,16) it will give image2[image]

I want to neglect image2 kind of images.i.e images with only background

Comment: Something went wrong when you pasted the images. I can only see one image at the moment.

Comment: I have added the image again

Comment: If i get another image like image 2 while splitting that item,the image should be neglected